# php secure login not displaying content after logging in

Tags: php, html, sql

i have a login script and register script in php, i have registered successfully but when i am trying to log in, the content is being hidden showing am not logged in, but the log in is happening, my code is like below for the display page:

```html
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login: Protected Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
            <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
            <p>
                Hello
            </p>
            <p>Return to <a href="index.php">login page</a></p>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p>
                <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

my login process code:

```html
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success
        header('Location: ../protected_page.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page.
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

functions code:

```html
<?php
include_once 'psl-config.php';

function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = true;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"],
        $cookieParams["domain"],
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
}



function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible.
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password
        FROM members
       WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted. We are using
                // the password_verify function to avoid timing attacks.
                if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/",
                                                                "",
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512',
                              $db_password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) {
    // Get timestamp of current time
    $now = time();

    // All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours.
    $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time
                             FROM login_attempts
                             WHERE user_id = ?
                            AND time > '$valid_attempts'")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);

        // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        // If there have been more than 5 failed logins
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Check if all session variables are set
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'],
                        $_SESSION['username'],
                        $_SESSION['login_string'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password
                                      FROM members
                                      WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$user_id" to parameter.
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // If the user exists get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if (hash_equals($login_check, $login_string) ){
                    // Logged In!!!!
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not logged in
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not logged in
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in
        return false;
    }
}

function esc_url($url) {

    if ('' == $url) {
        return $url;
    }

    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\x80-\xff]|i', '', $url);

    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $url = (string) $url;

    $count = 1;
    while ($count) {
        $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
    }

    $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

    $url = htmlentities($url);

    $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $url);
    

    if ($url[0] !== '/') {
        // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
        return '';
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

can anyone please tell me whats wrong wih my code

Comment: We need to see the content of the `login_check()` function. The problem probably is in there.

Comment: @LLJ97 i have updated the question

Comment: I can't see you start the session anywhere in your `login_check()` function. If you want to work with `$_SESSION`, you need to start it first.

Comment: i start it in my login proces page

Comment: AFAIK you need to put it on every page you work with. Otherwise the session will not be available on that page.

Comment: what about the funtions page? where should i put it?

Comment: thats not the problem, session is already startd its saying

Comment: You should debug the code since, as far as I can see, there are no obvious mistakes in the code or in the sql statements.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @dharman may i know how?

Comment: `VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')`. It might not be directly vulnerable, but the mere idea that you do not use prepared statements everywhere suggest that you might still be vulnerable. It is best that you use prepared statements always. Don't make any exceptions.